# Datadog 'page' is invalid: invalid cursor

Tags: shell, datadog, datadog-dashboard, terraform-provider-datadog

```
  cursor=$(echo $response | jq -r .meta.page.after)
```

data='{
"filter": {
"from": "now",
"to": "now-2d",
"query": "*"
},
"page": {
"cursor": "{{cursor}}",
"limit": 1000
}
}'
data=$(echo $data | sed "s/{{cursor}}/$cursor/")

response =$(curl -k POST "https://api.datadoghq.com/api/v2/rum/events/search" 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "DD-API-KEY: $DATADOG_API_KEY" 
-H "DD-APPLICATION-KEY: $DATADOG_APP_KEY" 
--data-raw "$data")

echo $response >> outputenter code here

when I execute the above scripts to extract the data dog rum events logs and getting the error
**"input invalidation error(Field 'page' is invalid: invalid cursor)** can someone help on this.